# How to overlay two transparent background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to overlay few background images, of two different divs, I am using transparent PNGs but when I overlay one over the other the second adds some annoying white background over the first and the effect is lost. I have read somewhere that this might be due to the alpha channel, but did not have any info for the walkthrough. Could someone point me to a solution ?

**Please Note** I am using a sprite and take both images from there, jQuery is included as well (so I will accept JS or jQuery solution), I need to use a transparent images, cannot use opaque, cannot combine the images. I currently I am using `z-index: 1;` for the bottom layer and `z-index:2;` for the top, probably will have a third one so the solution should not be centered over overlaying two images, but to overlay 2+ images.

Thanks!

[The Image I am using](http://tinypic.com/r/16pc2v/6)

Added a [fiddle with comment in the JS section](http://jsfiddle.net/626qd/1/)

[A screenshot of the result](http://tinypic.com/r/2hf5pmp/6) notice the white between the leafs in the left upper corner and it is supposed to be a 35px square containing a little dirt

**Solution:**

By using CSS and adding `background-color: transparent;` I have removed the background color of the divs and obtained full transperancy

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: What about setting a jsfiddle?

Comment: Check your divs to see if they have a background colour, then check your PNG and make sure they are actually transparent

Comment: I am going to create a fiddle in a few seconds

Comment: Where's the images?  GIMP *is* capable of making transparent GIFs, but that doesn't mean they *are*.

Comment: there is the image and I am not using GIF, but PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` is not necessarily transparent by default. It inherits the background of it's parent. Which is most likely white, and not transparent..

Try:

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)">.........</div>
```

Comment: tried with the container div by setting its background to rgba(0,0,0,0) but did not work. Probably it is not the best idea but I have tried anything I could think of...

Comment: Then your images are probably not completely transparent. Could you provide a screenshot, fiddle or anything else which allows us to see the effect?

Comment: there is a fiddle and the image I want to use is is in a link and will add screen in a few moments.